# Help with being unable to select a specific object

Tags: objects

I have four objects (planes) that I have worked on, and I applied image textures, etc., and they display OK in the wireframe/solid/render views, but for some reason I now can't select them, and they aren't even showing in the outliner at all (they still show if I hide all the items in the outliner).

Any ideas? Is it something dumb that I've clicked?

I am using Blender 2.76b.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxBRmMnKdkzFYmY3aFJSOEU3Uk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: or even upload the file? (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is permanent)

Comment: The possible reason why object isn't shown in the Outliner is that it's parented to another one, hence it'll be shown in hierarchy of the parent (which can be anything). It won't explain why object is unselectable though and it's hard to judge given the provided information. Please consider uploading the file as it's recommended already, thanks.

Comment: The file is 11Mb so if that's not a problem I'll upload it

Comment: The plane is there. It is selected. You can see the word "plane" highlighted in the outliner. That means it's selected. The eye icon is greyed out though.  You also have a gazillion other planes (plane.001, plane.002...). They all have their eye icon greyed out too. That means you can't see any of them in the view window. Also, you are on the wrong layer. The plane is on layer 15. You can tell because the little dot on that layer is orange. You are currently on layer 1.

Answer (score 3):

The object could be inhibited from selection (arrow icon disabled in the outliner), but maybe currently outliner is also set to show only other scenes, or object types (ie: outliner is not set to "All scenes") so you don't see it, atm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All the arrow icons are displayed and All scenes selected (I've tried every view to try to find it!!)

Comment: Do they get selected with CTRL-A?

Comment: @morp I did notice you have multiple layers. Have you tried looking through all your layers?

Comment: Yep looked through every bloody layer (repeatedly just in case the buggers were hiding) :)

Comment: They can't be selected with any method. It may be worth adding that it was originally a SketchUp dae file imported , but as I have worked on the objects in question I didn't think it relevant.

Comment: try also appending their mesh (not object) to another fresh file, and assign the appended mesh to a native object. If they behave correctly, save the file and import them back in the current .blend

Comment: But I can't find any trace of it (apart from in the view windows) so not sure how I can do anything. I guess I'll have to transfer everything else on that layer to another and ignore that layer and redo the objects. Thanks for all your help though - much appreciated